# I don't know why it pops up "runtime error". Is there any steps I missed :(

Tags: c

To scan two files which only include numbers. Combining and sorting all of the numbers. I have tried so many times but it still pops up an error message.

Please tell me if anyone knows where the problem is. Thank you so much!!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 128

int main(){
    int i, j, temp, count=0;
    int data1[N];
    char fname1[N], fname2[N];
    
    scanf("%s", fname1);
    FILE *f1 = fopen(fname1, "r");
    
    while(1){
        fscanf(f1, "%d", &data1[i]);
        i++;
        if(feof(f1)){
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    fclose(f1);
    
    scanf("%s", fname2);
    FILE *f2 = fopen(fname2, "r");
    
    while(1){
        fscanf(f2, "%d", &data1[i]);
        i++;
        if(feof(f2)){
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    fclose(f2);
    
    for(j=count; j>1; j--){
        for(i=0; i<j-1; i++){
            if(data1[i]>data1[i+1]){
                temp = data1[i];
                data1[i] = data1[i+1];
                data1[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        printf("%d ", data1[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The inputs:

```
2 5 9 10 15 18 18 20 30 58
```

```
1 3 10 12 19 22 25 28 40
```

The output:

```
1 2 3 5 9 10 10 12 15 18 18 19 20 20 22 25 28 30 58
```

Comment: We can't tell how you have compiled it, or how you are running it and what input you are giving it.

Comment: @せいが You are using the uninitialized variable i     while(1){
        fscanf(f1, "%d", &data1[i]);
        i++;

Comment: Check the return values of `fopen` and `fscanf`. You also have to make sure you don't write past the end of `data`.

Comment: i must be initialized by 0. It need to check that from file already got N symbols. Numbers in files must be less than 128 or less than 255 if data1 will be declared like unsigned char or read bytes but not int.

Comment: Your output is missing “40”, is that a typo on your part?

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers. Very useful!!! ;-;
I also found that the .txt was saved in a folder `../app/.txt`. Is it possible to open the .txt by typing the file name of .txt only

Comment: Not typo. I am not sure what is wrong... Still checking it.

Comment: I solved it!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you all of you guys!!
Love you all!!!!